# Django Class Based View CreateView url resolution

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I am fairly new to CBV and am trying to make sense of it. I copied the following example from the django doc page:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

## models.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('author-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

## views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorCreate(CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']

class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']

class AuthorDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Author
    success_url = reverse_lazy('author-list')
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from myapp.views import AuthorCreate, AuthorUpdate, AuthorDelete

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    url(r'author/add/$', AuthorCreate.as_view(), name='author_add'),
    url(r'author/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', AuthorUpdate.as_view(), name='author_update'),
    url(r'author/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', AuthorDelete.as_view(), name='author_delete'),
)
```

At author/add/ I indeed get the form, but when I enter the string I get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'author-detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 3}' not found.
```

It seems like the new entry has been added to the database, but it could not resolve the URL for the next view?

So I am puzzled, what is this get_absolute_url() object's method supposed to do, how does it work (I could not grasp it from the django doc) and how do I fix the issue?
Thanks.

EDIT 1: added the template:

author_form.html:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

Comment: None of your urls have the name `author-detail`. Are you getting this error after submitting the form?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the code I am running with and the error message I am getting after submit.

Answer (score 4):

By default, when a new model is created django will redirect you to a models absolute url as returned by the `get_absolute_url` method. In your example you would need to add a url with the name `author-detail` that accepts a `pk` keyword argument.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  # ...
  url(r'author/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', AuthorDetail.as_view(), name='author-detail'),
)
```

Note the name of the url matches the name of the view in the `get_absolute_url` method.

Use it in your templates:

```
{% for author in authors %}
  <a href="{{author.get_absolute_url}}">{{author.name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you'd use a custom view, you should, hence have a view (i.e. in the `views.py` file) that accepts the `pk` argument, as in `def MyCustomDetailView(request, pk):`